# How to set canOverrideExistingModule=true in React Native for Android Apps?

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-virtual-device

I built an android app using React Native, it got built successfully but when I run the app in my Android Virtual Device it shows up a full red screen with the following error:

[image]

**I have not done native app development ever before neither do I have any knowledge of Java so I have no idea what this error means and how to fix this.**

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The name of the package associated to this error is not `AirMapModule` but `MapsPackage` from `com.airbnb.android.react.maps`.

In your `MainApplication.java` in directory : `android/app/src/main/java/../../` remove any duplicate entry of :

- the import package : `import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage`
- the call to the constructor of the module : `new MapsPackage()` in function `getPackages`

Comment: The first bullet is mentioned everywhere online, but this was the first mention of the second place to look for duplicates. Thank you.

Comment: This error rise when you are trying to import same package twice in MainApplication.java file

Comment: this works but everytime i link a library it repeat itself

Comment: just remove the duplicate imports from MainApplication.java

Comment: This answer is most assuredly the one you're looking for if you ended up here

Comment: If you still get the error even after removing duplicates, you may need to remove (comment) `packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());` lines for the packages that are already auto-linked (no manual installation)

Comment: Could someone please take a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69201505/react-native-native-module-nativeunimoduleproxy-tried-to-override-nativeunimodu

Answer (score 43):

Go to file "MainApplication.java" (under `.\android\app\src\main\java\com\projectName\`)

Make sure that under `getPackages()` function you don't have duplicate lines (in my case I had "new MapsPackage()" twice).

Fix duplicate imports as well.

Answer (score 23):

Open the **`MainApplication.java`** file by this address: `android/app/src/main/java/com/projectName/MainApplication.java` and add the following code to `MainApplication.java` file:

```java
@Override    
public boolean canOverrideExistingModule() {        
  return true;    
}
```

And everything became correct.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by native module? library? I'm getting an error "module does not override method from it's superclass"

Comment: Can someone please be more specific about this solution? Please tell us what and where ...

Comment: Thank you @Andew Fan for actually answering the question

Comment: @ThembelaniM you can add the override function to the native module's class that extends `ReactContextBaseJavaModule`

Comment: Where exactly should one add this snippet?

Comment: Can you check if this goes into the MainApplication.java? Because upon adding this I get an error saying that you can not override a method that is not present in the supertype

Comment: @ShreyasShandilya please look at this answer I just added, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846452/how-to-set-canoverrideexistingmodule-true-in-react-native-for-android-apps/63438974#63438974

Answer (score 15):

Go to the **MainAplication file**.

Remove duplicate package and remove duplicate package in `getPackages()` method

```java
  @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage()
      );
    }
```

Then after try this command in your terminal :

- **cd android**
- **./gradlew clean**

Answer (score 12):

The above solutions are all correct, but let me explain a little bit,some of above solutions suggest to override the following method.

```
@Override    
public boolean canOverrideExistingModule() {        
  return true;    
}
```

But **question** is where to override? first of all, you can't override inside MainActivity.java or MainApplication.java file.

You should override it in the class inside some node_modules project folder and that class will be extending from  **ReactContextBaseJavaModule** class.

In my case, it was not getting repeated in imports/adding duplicate packages but it was mainly because of  auto linking at the and that was making it to repeat.

I am using react-native-contacts npm package to interact so what I did is that went inside

```
node_modules\react-native-contacts\android\src\main\java\comrt2zz\reactnativecontacts\ 
ContactsManager.java
```

and this **ContactsManager** was extending from the **ReactContextBaseJavaModule** and I override there and got the problem resolved.

So as general there could be a **lot** of classes that will be extending from **ReactContextBaseJavaModule** under different projects inside node_modules, but you need to go for specific a project that will be creating duplication problem and there you should override it.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for. it worked for me, for react-native-contacts

Answer (score 11):

If the version of RN you're using is >= 0.60 then there is the possibility that auto-linking and your manual linking are doing the same thing twice. You have two options:

1- You can revert code changes in `getPackages` method
2- You can disable auto linking in `react-native-config.js` file.

Comment: I was doing exactly same as you mentioned :). Thanks buddy.

Comment: in v0.61.5, this was the answer for me. very un-suspecting

Answer (score 4):

You can remove your package from
MainApplication.java

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: its not solution we need this package in app

Answer (score 3):

Go to your module (coz of which you are getting this error message) Open the module.. add this code to it...

```
@Override    
public boolean canOverrideExistingModule() {        
  return true;    
}
```

Comment: which file inside the module?

Comment: @globefire look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846452/how-to-set-canoverrideexistingmodule-true-in-react-native-for-android-apps/63438974#63438974

Answer (score 2):

You can try check in file `MainApplication.java` in directory : `android\app\src\main\java` is have any duplicate package AirMapModule exist or not, and delete 1 if have.

Comment: There is neither a package nor even a variable by the name AirMapModule in the file MailApplication.java :(

Comment: what version of react-native you use ?

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.36.0

Comment: Did you try to check file `MainActivity.java` in the same directory too ?

Comment: Yeah, i just did. Even that doesn't have anything related to AirMapModule. :(

Comment: Hmm, i usually get this error by using react native link, it duplicate package when it already import in file. Hope you will get an answer soon.

Comment: Yeah i hope so. Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846452/how-to-set-canoverrideexistingmodule-true-in-react-native-for-android-apps/63438974#63438974

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Goto `android/app/src/main/java/YOURPACKAGE/MainApplication.java`

Find method `getPackages();`

Remove this `packages.add(new MapsPackage());`

Chill Pill! :)

Comment: this is not an answer man ((

Answer (score 1):

Add only the modules which are not autolinked at here,

```
        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for 
          // example: packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());         
          return packages;
        }
```

If the module is autolinked and added the module here, you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

check your `MainApplication.java`, in particular `protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages()`; the `AirMapModule` is probably twice in the list

Answer (score 0):

just remove `packages.add(new MapsPackage());` this line MainApplication.java

Answer (score -1):

if installed library react-navigation you can run via android studio.
else remove library react-navigation and just yarn it's will work.