# getPackages() method in MainApplication.java, the module might be created twice

Tags: android, react-native, razorpay

[image]
I'm trying to integrate Razorpay with my react-native application using there official documentation from- https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/react-native-integration/standard/android/ but I'm getting this exception while running the application. No duplicate imports are there inside the MainApplication.java.

Answer (score 18):

In step 2 of setting up react-native-razorpay, I was adding these 2 lines in *MainApplication.java*:

```java
import com.razorpay.rn.RazorpayPackage;
```

and

```java
packages.add(new RazorpayPackage());
```

I got rid of this error by removing these 2 lines. The package is automatically added later on during build time by autolinking. Removing these 2 lines solved my issue.

Comment: This is the exact solution with proper reasoning. The Razorpay docs seems out of date regarding these steps.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar error but with a different package. Looks as though the packages are added much later I have no idea when and how though. React Native `"^0.64.0"`

> Native module Orientation tried to override OrientationModule. Check
> the getPackages() method in MainApplication.java, it might be that
> module is being created twice.

**Solution**

In `MainApplication.java`:

1. I had to remove or comment out **duplicate** import of OrientationPackage

> `// import com.github.yamill.orientation.OrientationPackage; <----- Commented out or removed`

2. And **not add** the package to `List<ReactPackage>`

> `// packages.add(new OrientationPackage()); //  <----- Commented out or removed`

Answer (score 2):

We need to check if any duplicate imports are there or not, or if any duplicate lines are there inside getPackages() method. If the issue is still not resolved then we need to add the following lines of code inside the module class(which extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule) inside node_modules folder...

Refer to this link for a similar problem I found on stackoverflow-

[How to set canOverrideExistingModule=true in React Native for Android Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846452/how-to-set-canoverrideexistingmodule-true-in-react-native-for-android-apps)

```
@Override    
  public boolean canOverrideExistingModule() {        
    return true;    
  }
```

Comment: Hey @Sandip, can you please point out the exact files where you added this snippet? I am facing the exact same issue.

Comment: @globefire Inside android node_modules package check for the java module class which is extending ReactContextBaseJavaModule there you have to add those lines. Sorry for such a late reply

Comment: Never mind @Sandip, there's some technical issue from razorpay, they asked me to downgrade the version

Answer (score 0):

It appears that React Native's update mechanism includes an auto-linking feature. Consequently, when you attempt to manually add a new package instance, it may result in a duplication error within your application. This can occur because React Native is already managing the linking process for you. Instead of manually injecting the new package, consider reviewing the documentation or release notes for the update version to understand how to properly integrate the changes without causing duplication errors.

For me the solution that works, was only not manually link the new package.