# Problem with accessing contacts on React-Native Android

Tags: android, react-native, contacts

I have implemented all the installation instructions for working with contacts, but for some reason it does not work for me.

I have tried all the solutions offered here including a number of different examples of code.

The problem seems to be related to adding the package to the MainApplication.java file :

```
@Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
      packages.add(new ReactNativeContacts());  <---- The package I added
      return packages;
    }
```

The reason I think so is because if I delete this line, after clicking the button, the warn is activated with the comment "No permission" (attached pic.).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqsOT.png)

And if I run the code with this line (which mentioned above), then I get this error: (attached pic.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5BDX.png)

Below I have attached pictures of App.js, package.json, MainApplication.java :

// App.js

```
import React, { useState, Component } from 'react';
import { Appbar } from 'react-native-paper';
import { View, StyleSheet, Header, StatusBar, Image, Text, SafeAreaView, ImageBackground, Button, Platform, PermissionsAndroid, requestMultiple  } from 'react-native';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';

class App extends Component {
   async requestContactsPermission() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      return true
    } else {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_CONTACTS,
      ]);
      if (
        granted['android.permission.READ_CONTACTS'] === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.granted &&
        granted['android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS'] === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.granted
      ) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
  }

  getContaxt = () => {
    this.requestContactsPermission().then((didGetPermission) => {
      if (didGetPermission) {
        Contacts.getAll((err, Contacts) => {    ///Contacts.get
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }
          console.warn(Contacts)
        })
      } else {
        alert('no permission')
      }
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Load contacts" onPress={this.getContaxt}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin:10
  }
})
export default App;
```

// package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyTest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-contacts": "^7.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.18.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.18.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.67.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

// MainApplication.java

```
package com.mytest;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.config.ReactFeatureFlags;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.mytest.newarchitecture.MainApplicationReactNativeHost;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;
import com.rt2zz.reactnativecontacts.ReactNativeContacts;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          packages.add(new ReactNativeContacts());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  private final ReactNativeHost mNewArchitectureNativeHost =
      new MainApplicationReactNativeHost(this);

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      return mNewArchitectureNativeHost;
    } else {
      return mReactNativeHost;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the TurboModule system
    ReactFeatureFlags.useTurboModules = BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.mytest.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve the issue and checked your code you have to make changes in below files

setting.gradle  file you only have to insert below line

```
include ':react-native-contacts'
project(':react-native-contacts').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-contacts/android')
```

Build.gradle you only have to insert below line in dependencies

```
implementation project(':react-native-contacts')
```

ManiApplication.java file you only have to insert below line

```
import com.rt2zz.reactnativecontacts.ReactNativeContacts;
```

AndroidManifest.xml you have to add below lines

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

And checked your app.js file also you have done some mistakes like

You have done some error below If condition
which was you have to check **PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED** not
**PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.granted** for both.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button, Platform, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';
class App extends Component {
  async requestContactsPermission() {
   if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
   return true
  } else {
  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_CONTACTS,
  ]);
  // You have done some error below If condition 
  // which was you have to check PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED  not PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.granted for both.
  if (
    granted['android.permission.READ_CONTACTS'] === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED &&
    granted['android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS'] === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED
  ) {
    console.log('granted if ==>> ');
    return true
  } else {
    console.log('granted else ==>> ');
    return false
    }
  }
}
getContaxt = () => {
this.requestContactsPermission().then((didGetPermission) => {
  if (didGetPermission) {
    Contacts.getAll()
      .then(contacts => {
        console.log("Contacts ==>> ", contacts);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log("e ==>> ", e);
      });
   } else {
    alert('no permission')
    }
  })
}
render() {
  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Button title="Load contacts" onPress={this.getContaxt} />
  </View>
   );
  }
 }
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
 flex: 1,
 justifyContent: "center",
 alignItems: "center",
 backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
 },
 welcome: {
  fontSize: 20,
  textAlign: 'center',
  margin: 10
 }
})
export default App;
```

Comment: -1


I manage to fix this error with this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63438974/12745069

But no when I press the button I get this error : enter image description here